# Downloading multiple pdf files with bash

Tags: python, bash

I’d like to download from https://hebrewbooks.org/ all free available books, using a simple script.

Every book (52,000 of them) has a unique numeric number assigned. For example: 
`https://hebrewbooks.org/1 
https://hebrewbooks.org/3 
https://hebrewbooks.org/52000`

But many numbers have been skipped or have been removed.

Usually a visitor would click on the download button which returns: (book number 52000)

`https://download.hebrewbooks.org/downloadhandler.ashx?req=52000`

Or (for book number 1)

`https://download.hebrewbooks.org/downloadhandler.ashx?req=1`

I would like to download all files to a local disk without having to request each file individually in a browser etc.

I know this can been achieved with a simple script (even a bash script).

Could anyone advise me where to look or where find a similar problem that’s been solved.

Edit: I forgot an important question. How do I get the script to change the name for each downloaded file from the I’d number (such as 42000) to the metadata included in each file?

Comment: well... maybe this questions is off-topic... But yes, you can download pages via bash (wget or curl commands) or python (urllib.urlretrieve)

Comment: for i in {1..52000}; do wget -c "https://download.hebrewbooks.org/downloadhandler.ashx?req=$i" ; done

Comment: Thanks, your code works. But I get 429 error, is there a way to wait a while after every couple of requests?

Comment: Add `sleep 1;` before the `wget` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, wget would be a good tool to use. Maybe try using it in a loop?

```
#! /bin/bash

#iterate 52,000 times
for i in {1..52000}; do

  sleep 1s
  wget [local path] "https://download.hebrewbooks.org/downloader.ashx?req=${i}" 

  # $i is the current iteration, therefore collecting all 52,000

done
```

**edit**: Just realized someone commented this on the main question, but I'll leave this here for anyone who doesn't see them like me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget for this task:

```
wget /download/path/to/save/downloaded/file "https://download.hebrewbooks.org/downloader.ashx?req=book_number"
```

More help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/207265/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-website-via-terminal